# Proving a language is not regular

Tags: regular-languages

I need to prove that the following language is not regular

> $\{c^mb^na^n \mid n>0,m\geq0\}$

But I am not sure how to do that for this particular one. I vaguely understand pumping lemma, but every example I see is in the form

> $\{a^nb^n \mid n>0\}$

Or something similiar.  This does not help me with my problem, because I dont fully understand pumping lemma and am not sure how to do it for two variables that have no dependency on each other.  I know to take a length P from L, and I also need a string s>=P.
Which then becomes P=xyz, but it is this step that confuses me.

Comment: Hm. You're planning to show that something is not regular, but you don't understand the pumping lemma? That's not going to work. You could try Myhill-Nerode, but most find that more difficult.

Comment: The language of words $c^mb^n$ would be regular. It's the $ab$ part you need to think about. The $m$ is largely irrelevant to the proof. In particular, the word $c^0b^na^n$ is in the language.

Comment: Okay, so I could finish the pumping lemma like |xy|<=n, y=a^k where 0<k<=n, x=a^q where 0<=q<m, z=a^(n-k-q)b^n.  then go say xyyz, which would leave a^(k+n)b^(n), which is not a regular language as (k+n)!=n?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this. Here are some:

1. If $L = \{c^m b^n a^n : n>0, m\geq 0\}$ were regular then so would $L \cap b^*a^*$ be.
2. The words $\{ b^n : n > 0 \}$ are pairwise inequivalent modulo $L$, so $L$ is irregular according to Myhill-Nerode.
3. The pumping lemma works if you ignore the $c$ part.